# Running tests against source code or the package

Tags: pytest, setuptools, python-unittest, python-packaging, tox

I've written some Python that I'm distributing as a custom package. I have some tests that I run against the source code while I'm developing, but I also want users who install the package to be able to run the same tests against the distributed package.

My package follows this structure:

```
my_package
├── MyPackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_module.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── test_my_package.py
```

The `my_package.py` is

```py
def my_function():
    print("here!")
    return True
```

And `test_my_package.py` is:

```py
import unittest

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../")
from MyPackage.my_module import my_function

class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_somehting(self):
        self.assertTrue(my_function())
```

As I'm manipulating `sys.path`, I'm always running the tests against the development code. Is there a way to use stuptools so I can run the tests against development code but the users run against the installed package?

Thanks!

Comment: Tools like `tox` (possibly in combination with `pytest`) should help with that. I would also recommend using a so-called _src-layout_.

Comment: @sinoroc, what do you mean by 'src-layout'?

Comment: Links: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure -- https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/ -- https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/issues/320

Comment: We're digressing a bit here. The post starts with "This is about packaging libraries, not applications.". My actual application is a script, should I consider it a library or an application? I'm following the folder pattern form [here](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: If I were you, I'd remove the `sys.path` manipulations in your test. Why would you need those? You probably need a better test runner. I think if you just use _pytest_ it would make things easier.

Comment: Also have you used editable installations to test against the current source code instead of the installed code? `python -m pip install --editable .`

Comment: @sinoroc, thanks for the suggestions! Turns out all I needed was `pip install -e .`.

Comment: nice! i'm glad.

Answer (score 2):

There is a misconception when you say "tests that I run against the source code while I'm developing".

You always should run your tests against the packaged code because you want to be sure that the packaged code, which your users will run, works.

You could use `tox` to run your tests which automatically creates a package from your source code and even runs the tests for different Python Versions, eg the currently supported Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8.

While it would be a very rare thing, your users could then run the tests also.

Comment: You can do both, can't you? I mean, it'd be very inconvenient to have to install the package every single time I run the tests because I'm using TDD, so I run the tests once a minute. I think editable gives me what I want.

Comment: Yes, you can, should do both. Run your tests on the regular with your project installed as editable. And at key steps (before git commits for example) run your tests on the actually installed (non-editable) project (tox can do that very well). And yes, it's quite rare that the users run the tests of the project, my compromise is I distribute the tests in the _sdist_ but not in the _wheel_.